# Dropdown menu Hover : Color not filling entirely background of wanted element

Tags: css, hover, background-color

```
.nav-main {
    background-color:#09F;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    color:#FFF;
    line-height:40px;
}
.nav-main .logo{
    float:left;
    padding: 40px 5px;
    font-size:1.4em;
    line-height: 20px;
        }
.nav-main > ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    }
.nav-main > ul > li {
    float:left;
    }
.nav-item{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 40px 15px;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    }
.nav-item:hover {
    background-color:#03C;

}
.nav-content {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#09F;
    opacity: .9;
    max-height:0px; 
    border:1px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #FFF;
}
.nav-content a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
.nav-content a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    background-color:#03C;
        }
.nav-sub {
    padding:20px;

}
.nav-sub ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.nav-sub ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    }

.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content{
    max-height:400px;
    -webkit-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
    }
```

Hello, 
I'm trying to fill the background of the hover element entirely with #03C but it's not working, would you be kind enough to explain this to me? So far it only fills the length of the text in the unordered list items. I started HTML5 & CSS yesterday, so I'm quite clueless about what's wrong here. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you have those rules applied to the right container element and not just what you think is the target?

Comment: Can you put your html and css into a JSFiddle and post the link to it? That makes it easier for people to work with the code. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/avp8dh6g/                                   thank you!!!

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but just a heads up, when displaying a Style-Sheet in a question devs are going to ask to see your HTML document to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the padding to the anchor-element (and not its container) in order for it to have the big background on-hover. I also changed the display on the anchor element from inline-block to block - otherwise they do not display full width in the nav container.

I amended your css:

```
.nav-sub {
  // removed the padding from here
}

.nav-sub ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-sub ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f1edrmo5/1/

I would also recommend you have a look at [HTML5 page structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure) - it's very helpful for keeping your page markup correct. I still look at it most days :-)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! Even though I do not understand why inline-block makes such a difference.  I only know that with inline block two copies of an element can sit side by side...Thank you again.

Comment: If this worked for you can you please mark the answer as correct? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I just did :) Can you provide a quick explanation though?

Comment: Here's an example of how inline works vs inline block vs block. You can see that block fills the entire width of the container, whereas inline-block applies the specified padding, but doesn't fill out the container width. You needed to fill out the width with your navigation hover state, hence the block.

I also applied padding to the various elements to illustrate how inline works vs the others. https://jsfiddle.net/mkbdo60p/1/